# Debian gnu/linux 9.11 python upgrade to 3.7

Tags: python, gnu

I am trying to upgrade python version from 3.5.3 to 3.7.5 in Debian gnu/linux 9.11 setup.
I followed this post's instruction. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/

It seemed to work well, but as I run in jupyter notebook I get these:

`!python --version`

Python 2.7.13

`!python3 --version`

Python 3.5.3

`!python3.7 --version`

Python 3.7.5

How can I use python 3.7.5 as my default python?